# Alert in Eclipse about the Java Scanner

Tags: java, eclipse

Can anyone teach me how to duel with it?

Two alert sign appear when I was coding in Eclipse and I don't know how to rip it off.

It's all about the `scanner`.

The code and the place and the content of the alert:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

    public class test2 {

        private static Scanner number; //alert:The value of the field test2.number is not used

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            boolean run = true;

            while(run){

                int target = (int) Math.round(Math.random()*100), guest;

                Scanner number = new Scanner( System.in ); //alert:Resource leak: 'number' is never closed

                System.out.println("Guest a number:");
                guest = number.nextInt();

                String result = (guest == target) ? "You make it!!!": "Try again";
                System.out.println(result);
                System.out.println("The Target is " + target);

            }

        }

    }
```

p.s. Actually,This program is worked without any problem,I think.

Comment: You are never using your `number` field, and you are never invoking `number.close()`. That is why you are are receiving those warnings from Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You can use try with resources to manage the resources.

```
int target = (int) Math.round(Math.random()*100), guest;

try(Scanner number = new Scanner( System.in )) {

    System.out.println("Guest a number:");
    guest = number.nextInt();

    String result = (guest == target) ? "You make it!!!": "Try again";
    System.out.println(result);
    System.out.println("The Target is " + target);
} catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Also remove the global unused variable `number`